# logstash influxdb output plugin - how to send integer

Tags: logstash, influxdb

I am using logstash-output-influxdb plugin to send event from logstash to influx db. Data points configuration of plugin look like

```
data_points => {
          "visitor" => 1
          "lead" => 0
          "category" => "%{[category]}"
          "host" => "%{[host]}"
}
```

But here problem is visitor and lead fields in influxdb are integer and using above configuration results in following error

**input field \\"visitor\\" on measurement \\"visitors_new\\" is type float, already exists as type integer.**

Line protocol of influxdb says that you have to append i with the number to indicate that it is an integer, so if I change my configuration to

```
data_points => {
          "visitor" => "1i"
          "lead" => "0i"
          "category" => "%{[category]}"
          "host" => "%{[host]}"
}
```

Now error becomes

**input field \\"visitor\\" on measurement \\"visitors_new\\" is type string, already exists as type integer**

If I change configuration to

```
data_points => {
          "visitor" => 1i
          "lead" => 0i
          "category" => "%{[category]}"
          "host" => "%{[host]}"
}
```

**Now logstash does not accept it as a valid configuration.**

How can I send integer fields to influxdb using logstash-output-influxdb plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using [the `coerce => { }` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-influxdb.html#plugins-outputs-influxdb-coerce_values) to achieve your data-typing, rather than feeding line-protocol details in the number.

```
data_points => {
      "visitor" => 1
      "lead" => 0
      "category" => "%{[category]}"
      "host" => "%{[host]}"
}
coerce_values => {
      "visitor" => "integer"
      "lead"    => "integer"
}
```

This tells the *plugin* these fields are integer, which will likely be more successful.